# check all socket opened in linux OS

Tags: c, linux

My program opens a socket with this function:

> sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)

After finish sending data the socket is closed:

> close(sockfd);

But the issue is when the program doesn't run well and is blocking. Thereby the socket will not be closed.

How can I check all sockets opened under Linux OS ?

Comment: Ask for a list of opened "files" lsof

Comment: If you need to handle in code, you should maintain a list of valid sockets and close whenever needed.

Comment: little off topic, You should check value of socketfd(returned from socket) for better error handling.

Comment: yes, the socket number is the same each time the socket is created !

Comment: If a process terminates all its file descriptors are closed (by the kernel).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch but sockets can live on in a [zombie state](http://www.linuxmisc.com/9-unix-programmer/e498075e5b007752.htm) for a short time after termination.

Comment: On CentOS `lsof` doesn't list RAW sockets... only TCP/UDP. Chankeys answer worked for me... `cat /proc/net/raw`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> /proc/net/tcp -a list of open tcp sockets
>
> /proc/net/udp -a list of open udp sockets
>
> /proc/net/raw -a list all the 'raw' sockets

These are the files, use `cat` command to view them. For example:

`cat /proc/net/tcp`

You can also use the `lsof` command.

> lsof is a command meaning "list open files", which is used in many
>   Unix-like systems to report a list of all open files and the processes
>   that opened them.

Comment: these commands  don't work in ubuntu (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3))

===> **root@root:/home/aa/test# /proc/net/**

:::::
**dev_snmp6/ netfilter/ rpc/       stat/**

Comment: these are files, use cat command to view, like `cat /proc/net/tcp`

Comment: It's usually easier to use `lsof` instead of these.

Comment: `lsof` doesn't list RAW sockets (at least not on CentOS). They do appear in `cat /proc/net/raw`

Comment: Specially, if you are willing to check the netlink sockets, see `/proc/net/netlink`, which shows all the netlink sockets including kernel.

Answer (score 65):

Also you can use **ss** utility to dump sockets statistics.

To dump summary:

```
ss -s

Total: 91 (kernel 0)
TCP:   18 (estab 11, closed 0, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         0         -         -        
RAW       0         0         0        
UDP       4         2         2        
TCP       18        16        2        
INET      22        18        4        
FRAG      0         0         0
```

To display all sockets:

```
ss -a
```

To display UDP sockets:

```
ss -u -a
```

To display TCP sockets:

```
ss -t -a
```

Here you can read ss man: [ss](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ss)

Comment: Thank you!  I absolutely love when I don't have to install a new RPM for every command I run!  This one was built in.

Answer (score 31):

You can use **netstat** command

> netstat --listen

To display open ports and established TCP connections,

> netstat -vatn

To display only open UDP ports try the following command:

> netstat -vaun

Comment: RAW ICMP sockets don't show up in netstat on my system. Chankeys answer works for me on CentOS `cat /proc/net/raw`

Comment: @tricky That's because you have to use *netstat -w -l*, or better still *ss -w -l*.  These commands will display *listening* raw sockets. If you want more info, use for instance *ss -w -lnp*.